# mplayer mingw 64bit signal 11

Tags: gdb, segmentation-fault, mplayer

with difficulty that I generated the executable. I get this error running

> MPlayer interrupted by signal 11 in module: demux_open
>
> - MPlayer crashed by bad usage of CPU/FPU/RAM.   Recompile MPlayer with --enable-debug and make a 'gdb' backtrace and   disassembly.
>     Details in DOCS/HTML/en/bugreports_what.html#bugreports_crash.
> - MPlayer crashed. This shouldn't happen.   It can be a bug in the MPlayer code *or* in your drivers *or* in your   gcc version. If you
>     think it's MPlayer's fault, please read   DOCS/HTML/en/bugreports.html
>     and follow the instructions there. We can't and   won't help unless
>     you provide this information when reporting a possible bug.

with gdb

I do not understand why that path, it's not my mingw.

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> 0x0000000001060853 in __gdtoa (fpi=, be=, bits=0x0, kindp=0x800, mode=0, ndigits=0, decpt=0x0, rve=0x0) at
>   c:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-svn/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/gdtoa.c:630
>
> 630     **c:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-svn/mingw-w64-crt/gdtoa/gdtoa.c**:
>   No such file or directory.

with new snapshot

> libavformat version 54.35.100 (internal)
>   MPEG-PS file format detected. VIDEO:  MPEG2  720x576  (aspect 3) 
>   25.000 fps  9800.0 kbps (1225.0 kbyte/s) Load subtitles in ../ [VO_SDL] Using driver: windib.
>   ========================================================================== Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
>   libavcodec version 54.71.100 (internal) [mpeg2video @
>   00000000016D96C0]Warning: not compiled with thread support, using thread emulation
>
> ## Selected video codec: [ffmpeg2] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-2)
>
> ========================================================================== Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders [ac3
>   @ 00000000016D96C0]Warning: not compiled with thread support, using
>   thread emulation
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> 0x00000000009d4fee in decode_frame ()